# Delete any substring that begins and ends with specific characters

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, split, flatten

I have strings that looks like this in google sheets:

In A1

`,information-technology#ICT / Computer`

In A2

`,agriculture#Agriculture / Agro-Allied,ngo#NGO/Non-Profit,project-management#Project Management`

I need to remove everything that begins with `,` and ends with `#` including these two characters

If possible the output to be separated by a comma like so

B1

```
ICT / Computer
```

B2

```
Agriculture / Agro-Allied, NGO/Non-Profit, Project Management
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A3, "#"))<>"", 
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3, "(#)", "$1♥"), 
 "♥"), "(,.+)", )&",", )),,9^9))), "^, |,$", ))
```

[image]